# What is the status of being dead or alive called?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

Having a bit of a discussion at work. We have a label that needs to be answered with deceased or alive, however we're not sure what to call the label. Status seems to be a bit too generic.

Is there a word to indicate the state of life of a being?

Comment: The state of life would be **`IsAlive=Yes|No`** or maybe **`IsDead=No|Yes`**

Comment: Can you supply details of the circumstances in which this label is applied?

Comment: One of the less common polysemes of _vitalness_ (or even _vitality_) would probably not be incorrect, but might not sound right because of the strong pull of other senses.

Comment: @WS2 A user will be required to enter some details about his parents and at one point he has to be enter if the parent is dead or alive.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Presently we went for a similar solution as it seems to be the most sensible way to ask for this particular information.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Indeed. Actually this might me one of the better sounding alternatives.

Comment: What about the Schrödinger's cat then?

Comment: Technically, it is called *Existence*, as in 'Certificate of Existence' and 'Letter of Existence,' and the field would be filled with 'Alive' or 'Deceased' as the case may be.

Comment: @Kris Your comment about Schrödinger's cat made me giggle as it did indeed come up during my search. I think you're quite right, Existence does encapsulate the states of life and death and it's most definitely the best sounding alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may not be a word sufficiently natural and succinct to use as a label in a software user interface, especially for such a delicate subject. Instead, I recommend simply labeling the field **Alive?** with a check box to indicate yes or no. Alternately you could provide two check boxes to choose from, **Alive** and **Deceased.**

On a paper form, where a bit more verbosity and instruction is reasonable, you could phrase this less tersely, although I would still recommend following the same basic principle of checking one of “Alive” or “Deceased” rather than trying to use an uncommon term to represent the concept.

---

**Update:** I checked out user49727's suggestion of **vital status** in [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vital%20status&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,vital%20status;,c0), and it looks like it's a legitimate term used by medical health professionals and genealogists. If that gives sufficient context for your users to complete the form, I recommend using it. However, if they must literally enter *alive* or *deceased* in a free-form field, I think the clearest way to indicate that is to label the field **Alive or Deceased?**

Comment: Why not 'Tick if still living'?

Comment: We used the label "Alive?" as unfortunately tick boxes or radio buttons are not an option.

My research into a specific word that encompasses the states of life and death wasn't very fruitful. At this point if such a word does exist, I'd imagine it would be rather exotic and not very appropriate for a software environment where you want to be as used user friendly as possible.

Comment: I am curious as well. I shall leave this question just a little longer to see if someone does come up with a word, but for my intents and purposes I think we can consider the question answered.

Comment: The other answer's suggestion of **vital status** is a good one, and if you decide to use it, you should accept that answer instead. However, on further thought I think the best label is **Alive or Deceased?**

Comment: Why is this down-voted?

Comment: If you went with *Alive* or *Deceased*, that'd be two **radio boxes** since the options are mutually exclusive. At least, that's the common terminology.

Answer (score 5):

It is called ***living status*** or preferably ***vital status***, as the former phrase has been used in wider contexts.

Comment: I actually quite like the ring of vital status (as similarly suggested by @EdwinAshworth). I'll consider changing what I have right now for this.

Comment: **Vital status** is an excellent suggestion, if it provides sufficient context to complete the form. I have updated my own answer with some additional information.

Comment: Could you add a citation for "living status"? I just googled it and the first result was [this scientific article](https://bmchealthservres.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12913-018-3215-6), which seems to be using it to mean *how* someone is currently living instead of *whether* they're currently living. The rest of the first page of results seem to be using it in similar ways too. That said, in OP's context it should be obvious; I'm imagining a drop-down menu where the options are "Alive" and "Deceased".

Answer (score 2):

Though it may sound a little bit odd:

[*aliveness*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/aliveness)
 - the quality of being alive

Comment: What is needed is a hypernym for *alive* & *dead*, not an affirmation of or degree of being alive. How would one fill the column 'Aliveness' with a word to say the person is deceased? "No"? "Nil"? "Not applicable"? "None Detectable"? ...

Comment: Just call it _Status_ and give it two values, _Alive_ and _Deceased_.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's literally "state". If you are to enquire about whether a person is alive or dead without literally asking "are they alive or dead?", you ask for their state.